# JPA ambiguous method call isMember

Tags: java, jpa, overloading, ambiguous

CriteriaBuilder has overloaded method isMember(...)

Create a predicate that tests whether an element is a member of a collection.

```
<E,C extends java.util.Collection<E>> 
Predicate isMember(E elem, Expression<C> collection) 

<E,C extends java.util.Collection<E>> 
Predicate isMember(Expression<E> elem, Expression<C> collection)
```

I got ambiguous compilation error for the following call:

```
CriteriaBuilder.isMember((Expression<Object>)a, (Expression<Collection<Object>>)b);
```

The member type can be any, so it is Object type.
How to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare an (unchecked) generic type to link the casts, perhaps in an internal private method to avoid it being visible to other callers.  This even compiles:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb;
Object a;
Object b;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <E> void isMember() {

    cb.isMember((Expression<E>) a, (Expression<? extends Collection<E>>) b);
}
```

Though `a` and `b` would be better as type `Expression`, and/or as local variables or parameters in the method for more local scoping.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for the compiler is that `(Expression<Object>)a` may also be of actual Type `E` which is just `Object`. In order to get the Method running you have to avoid the cast.

You can find a good example why this error occurs in this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29363060/3201917).

Comment: avoiding the cast don't help if the data structure should be so generic. i have this case and i guess the OP has the same kind of issue.